# Is there a way to forward email from Facebook?

Tags: gmail, facebook

I found a lot of information about forwarding email from other accounts *to* Facebook. But I could not find anything about going the other way. I want to forward email from my @facebook address to Gmail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s not exactly a forward per se, but you can use the notifications feature to receive the messages to your email address associated with your Facebook account—not the `@facebook.com` one, but the `@at_your_email_provider.com` one—which needs to be set as the primary email address. The problem is that it doesn’t discriminate between emails sent to `@facebook.com` and Facebook messages, it forwards everything. Also note that it’s not really reliable, sometimes the messages being delivered and sometimes not.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame Facebook's roach-motel business model doesn't allow a feature that real email has had for 30 or 40 years.